# Programmatically open PrefPane with section

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I need to open the network-prefpane in my App. This works fine with

```
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:@"/Path/To/PrefPane"];
```

But how can i directly open the "proxy-settings", which is in the "network-pref" under "advanced"?

You can see this in the Safari-Settings under "Advanced->Proxies"

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest and cleanest way I've found is to use Applescript.

```
NSAppleScript *a = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"System Preferences\"\nactivate\nset current pane to pane \"com.apple.preference.universalaccess\"\nend tell"];
[a executeAndReturnError:nil];
[a release];
```

Replace com.apple.preference.universalaccess with the name of the pane. [Here is a full list of preference pane names](http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20040317131326880).

Comment: This could be usable for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

While it's doable with UI scripting, it also requires access to assistive devices (System Preferences->Universal Access). That doesn't feel right because if a user prefers the access disabled, that just won't work. If you need to modify proxy settings you could use SystemConfiguration.framework directly, going through the necessary authentication.

Comment: I don't want to modify it. Just open it that the user can modify it himself.
Thanks for the info with the option in "universal access"